# Expectation Value for a multivariate probability distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, uniform-distribution

Is it possible to find the expectation value of the following object analytically?

$F(u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_N)=\prod_{i=1}^{N}(1-\alpha(u_i-u_{i-1})^2)$, where $u_{0}\equiv 0$. $u_i$'s are independent and identically distributed random variables from the uniform distribution $[-w/2,w/2]$.

Comment: I have modified the question. Sorry for the incompleteness.

Comment: It should be possible, but it is not going to be easy.  Since each consecutive factors of the product are not independent, you would have to expand it out.

Comment: Is it possible to write a closed form answer? What would be the best way of bookkeeping the terms? Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible to extract the large N limit of the above expression?